Parsing the opening of Ado's 新時代
The lyrics of the popular song 新時代 begin:
新時代はこの未来だ
世界中全部　変えてしまえば　変えてしまえば…
Clearly the repetition is just for emphasis, but I'm still unsure about my parsing:

I can understand 世界中 and 全部 separately, but without any particles I assume this is a noun phrase. How do the two parts go together? And should I understand this as the を-marked part of 変える, or just what?

The verb conjugation here is clearly 変え（る） + て + しま（う）+ えば. I only understand 〜えば as a conditional, but the translations I've found often use the potential here: "We can change the world" or similar. Where did that come from? Is it a valid understanding of the meaning, or just someone's attempt to make it poetic in English?

(possibly connected to the previous) My interpretation is that the sentence structure is inverted (notwithstanding the topic): regarding 新時代, if 世界中全部変えてしまう, then この未来だ. Is that a natural conclusion? Or is something instead elided after the 〜えば inflection (perhaps as simple as いい)?




Yes, を is omitted after 世界中全部. Words like 全体, 全部 and 全域 work as suffixes:

これ全部がダイヤモンドなの？
Is all of this diamond?
国民全体が賛成した。
The entire population agreed.
日本全域を探検した。
I explored all regions of Japan.

Alternatively, you can parse 全体 simply as an adverb that modifies 変えてしまう. For example, これ全部を食べる and これを全部食べる are interchangeable. But seeing how spaces are used in the lyrics, it may be more natural to parse 世界中全部 as a noun phrase.

Yes, 変えてしまえば is technically a conditional clause ("If we (dare) change it"). But what is the "result" part corresponding to this if-clause? One possibility is your interpretation (世界中全部変えてしまえば新時代はこの未来だ), but it's also fine to consider those two lines as two separate sentences. In this case, the result part of the if-clause is simply omitted, and the literal translation of the second line would be "If we change it...?" or "What if we change it?". And I think it's up to the translator's discretion to change this to "We can change it", since it's clear that they're positively expecting the change.

See above.


